# How to check float value entered by user in EditText is empty or not?

Tags: android, if-statement

I have made simple GST Calculator App, where user put amount and I show them results simple.
But when user not enter any input on editText, and submit button clicked, application is crashed.

So I want to show textview when edittext is empty.

But I don't know how to check.

I know about if else statments but, with float this is not working.

please tell me.

**this is my codes:**

```
    TextView textResults, textTotalGST, textErrorMessage; 
    EditText editAmount;
    Button btnSubmit;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textResults=findViewById(R.id.textResults);
            textTotalGST=findViewById(R.id.textTotalAmount);
            textErrorMessage=findViewById(R.id.textErrorMessage);
            editAmount=findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
            btnSubmit=findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                        float userAmount = Float.parseFloat(editAmount.getText().toString());
                        float gst_amount = (userAmount * 18) / 100;
                        float totalAmount = (userAmount - gst_amount);
                        
                        textResults.setText("GST :" + gst_amount);
                        textTotalGST.setText("Total: " + totalAmount);

                       // textErrorMessage.setText("Please enter the amount")
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you try: `editAmount.getText().length() == 0`  before parsing?

Comment: No i have not tried, can u explain properly

Comment: Thanks @dev.bmax, it's working. I added in (if (editAmount.getText().length() != 0))